# Getting Serial error while using pymata4 library

Tags: python, pyserial

I am using the pymata4 library for configuring with Arduino through python. The project was fine and working, but now after some months, when I am trying to run it, it is showing an Serial AttributeError.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCWWP.png)
Opening COM3...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Braile keyboard\real keyboard.py", line 4, in 
board = pymata4.Pymata4('COM3')
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymata4\pymata4.py", line 242, in **init**
self._manual_open()
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pymata4\pymata4.py", line 417, in _manual_open
self.serial_port = serial.Serial(self.com_port, self.baud_rate,
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

Any suggestions how to fix it??

I was trying to run the pymata4 code which was working fine before some months, but now it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

`pymata4` has been frozen for 3 years.  The PySerial module has changed its public interface.  You can try to tweak the code to use `serial_for_url`, or you can do as the package authors suggest and move to Telemetrix:

https://github.com/MrYsLab/pymata4?tab=readme-ov-file

Comment: Even after using Telemetrix, I am still getting the Serial error.
Here is the code--

Comment: # toggle the pin 4 times and exit
    for x in range(4):
        print('ON')
        await my_board.digital_write(pin, 1)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('OFF')
        await my_board.digital_write(pin, 0)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)        
# get the event loop
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

# instantiate telemetrix_aio
board = telemetrix_aio.TelemetrixAIO('COM3')

Comment: try:
    # start the main function
    loop.run_until_complete(blink(board, DIGITAL_PIN))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    loop.run_until_complete(board.shutdown())
    sys.exit(0)

Comment: Error-- 
self.my_serial = serial.Serial(com_port, baud_rate, timeout=1,
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'

Comment: What shall i do??

Comment: Is it possible you have a file called `serial.py` in your project?

Comment: No. I don't have any such file

Comment: In your application, if you do `import serial` and `print(serial.__file__)`, what location does it say?